# Creating isothermes, isochores etc

Tags: graphics, packages

May be the question goes beyond the purpose of [mathematica.stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) but I could not find anything similar with "googling".
Does it exist any Mathematica package/ application for creating isothermes, isobares, adiabatics and the like quickly and efficiently?

**EDIT**
I edit here the question in order to be more clear what I want. I leave also my answer as it is for the time being as it can be used as a guide.

In a pression-volume (volume:x, pression:y) I want an effiient way to represent, especially for cycles:
Isobares (pression=cst; that is lines parallel to the horizontal axis)
Isochores (volume=cst; that is lines parallel to the vertical axis)
Isothermes (pression=cst/volume; that is hyperbolae)
Adiabatics (pression=cst/volume^(gamma) where gamma>1)

I know to do it manually as the posted answer but I want a more quick way.

Comment: Would ListContourPlot do the work ?

Comment: There is also `ContourPlot` and `ContourPlot3D`, though `contourPlot3D` is often very slow

Comment: You question is not clear. Isotherms of what?. Any function/equation/data? This might help.
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/van-der-waals-isotherms/85831#85831

Comment: You should add more informations about the context of your question : Something like:  Thermodynamics/Pressure Volume Diagram, otherwise the reader imagine some interpretations that have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I edited the question. I think it is more clear now what I want (combing with my rough answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I post here a workaround I prepared. It's nothing special, but may be others find it also useful. Once I generalise it, I will post an upgrade.
This does not answer 100% the question; the quest of a package/application still remains:-)!

```
p1 = Plot[0.03/x, {x, 0.101, 0.3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}];

p2 = ContourPlot[{x == 0.1, y == 0.1}, {x, 0.0999, 0.299}, {y, 0.0999,
     0.299}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.4}, {0, 0.4}}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Blue, DotDashed}];

Show[{p2, p1}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
 Ticks -> {{{0.1, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(1\)]\)"}, {0.3, 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(2\)]\)"}}, {{0.1, 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\)"}, {0.3, 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(2\)]\)"}}}, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 14], 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, 0.05}], 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["V", 18], Style["P", 18]}, 
 Epilog -> {{PointSize[0.02], Point[{0.1, 0.1}], Point[{0.1, 0.3}], 
    Point[{0.3, 0.1}]}, 
   Text[Style["A (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(1\)]\))", 16], {0.095, 
     0.075}], 
   Text[Style["B (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\))", 16], {0.295, 
     0.075}], 
   Text[Style["C (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\))", 16], {0.095, 
     0.325}], {Arrowheads[0.04], Arrow[{{0.17, 0.08}, {0.23, 0.08}}], 
    Arrow[{{0.07, 0.23}, {0.07, 0.17}}], 
    Arrow[{{0.22, 0.15}, {0.17, 0.19}}]}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

```
p1 = Plot[{0.02/x, 0.01/x}, {x, 0.1, 0.2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Orange, Thick}}];

p2 = ContourPlot[{x == 0.1}, {x, 0.0999, 0.4}, {y, 0.2, 0.099}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.05, 0.25}, {0.0, 0.25}}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];

p3 = ContourPlot[{x == 0.2}, {x, 0.0999, 0.4}, {y, 0.05, 0.1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.05, 0.25}, {0.0, 0.25}}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Green, Thick}];

Show[{p2, p1, p3}, PlotRange -> {{0.075, 0.225}, {0.05/2, 0.225}}, 
 Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 14], 
 Ticks -> {{{0.1, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(2\)]\)=12,5"}, {0.2, 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(1\)]\)=25"}}, {{0.2, 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(3\)]\)=4"}, {0.05, 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\)=1"}, {0.1, 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(2\)]\)=2"}}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0.075, 0.025}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, 0.05}], 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["V (L)", 18], Style["P (bar)", 18]}, 
 Epilog -> {{PointSize[0.02], Point[{0.1, 0.1}], Point[{0.2, 0.05}], 
    Point[{0.2, 0.1}], Point[{0.1, 0.2}]}, 
   Text[Style["A", 16], {0.205, 0.04}], 
   Text[Style["B", 16], {0.098, 0.09}], 
   Text[Style["C", 16], {0.1, 0.21}], 
   Text[Style["D", 16], {0.2, 0.11}], 
   Rotate[Text[Style["T'=300K", 16], {0.15, 0.075}], -Pi/6], 
   Rotate[Text[Style["T=600K", 16], {0.15, 0.145}], -Pi/
     4], {Arrowheads[0.04], Arrow[{{0.1, 0.13}, {0.1, 0.16}}], 
    Arrow[{{0.2, 0.09}, {0.2, 0.06}}], 
    Arrow[{{0.14, 0.142857}, {0.16, 0.125}}], 
    Arrow[{{0.16, 0.0625}, {0.14, 0.0714286}}]}, {Dotted, 
    Line[{{0.075, 0.2}, {0.1, 0.2}}], 
    Line[{{0.075, 0.05}, {0.2, 0.05}}], 
    Line[{{0.1, 0.025}, {0.1, 0.15}}], 
    Line[{{0.2, 0.025}, {0.2, 0.05}}], 
    Line[{{0.075, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.1}}]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Lean and clean !

Comment: Thanks! I am happy you like it:-)!